# How to call a jquery function since html?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Good afternoon !

I have a simple problem , I have this code that works correctly.

```
<a onclick='flotante(1)' data-auction="+data.subastas[i].id+" class='tester btn btn-default col-md-12'>Pujar</a>
```

This code return the id of subasta , then I am using Laravel and PHP , when the user is log and click on Auction , I need to call a jquery function.

I have the following code

@if(Auth::user())
    AA
@else
    
            
                Inicio de sesión

```
             <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control margeninput"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control margeninput"/>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="row ">
                <input type="submit" id="singlebutton" class=" col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 " name="singlebutton" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></input> 
                </div>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
    </form>
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="bderrors">
    <p class="span-error">{{ $error }}</p>
     </div>
     @endforeach
```

@endif

However I try to use this

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("OK");
    </script>
@else
```

This code works when the user is login but not when user has doing click in auction.

Could anyone help to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read this questions and answers

**[How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)**

Maybe its more easy for you to do this *(like and ajax function that just call and controller and do a function "isLogin")*.

Comment: Ok for your answer I understan that I need to check if user isLogin , depence of the result I Can do one action or other action.